# Как создать в Android приложении файл txt , доступный для всех, видимый в эксплорере, с возможностью скопировать и т д?

Tags: android, файлы, txt

Подскажите, уважаемые,
Как создать файл txt из приложения на Android для общего доступа, чтобы его было видно другим приложениям, можно было редактировать любым редактором, скопировать на внешний носитель, переслать и т д.
Я очень начинающий в Android, и пример очень поможет, необходимый функционал:
приложение пишет файлы txt, потом их можно в этом же приложении посмотреть, выбрать, загрузить.
И чтобы эти файлы были видны в других приложениях.
Спасибо!

Comment: Нужно запросить у пользователя выбор файла, полученный `Uri` использовать для редактирования. Подробнее в офф. тренинге: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files.

Comment: Я получил uri , но не знаю , как прочитать содержимое файла. Можно пример?

Comment: Там же есть пример чтения текста: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#input_stream

Comment: Да, я не дочитал. Попробовал, но он читает только чужие файлы из видео, аудио и т д. А файл, который я записал в созданную с desktop-а папку, не читает. Если не затруднит, как мне решить мою задачу? Из моего приложения сохранять и загружать обратно текстовые файлы с их выбором через проводник, и чтобы их можно было забирать с телефона на другие устройства.

Comment: Если что-то не получается - опишите в вопросе подробнее что, приложите код, укажите желаемый и актуальный результат, тексты возникающих ошибок. По заголовкам в тренинге: __Create a new file__ - создаём, __Edit a document__ - записываем контент, __Open a document__ - открываем для чтения (просим юзера выбрать). С созданными/ранее открытыми файлами можно работать по полученным при этом `Uri`, для этого их можно сохранить в текстовом виде в преференсы, БД или любой другой приватный файл. Чтобы избежать потери доступа к файлу через `Uri` после перезагрузки аппарата: __Persist permissions__